# Paperclip attachement on customer form object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, paperclip, image-uploading

I've constructed a multi-step form with custom form objects for each step based on this railscast episode http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects.

In short, I have 4 step objects that look like this

```
class FormStep1
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :name, email

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true

  ...
```

I can now call validate on individual steps. Each of these objects also has a "submit" method which copies it's fields to another AllTheSteps model that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base

```
class AllTheSteps < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
```

So far this has worked great, but now I need to add a file attachment to one of the steps. I'm not sure how to go about it. I can include the validators in the FormStep object and add it to the logo field

```
class FormStep1
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include Paperclip::Validators

  attr_accessor :name, email, :picture

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates_attachment_file_name :picture, :matches => [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/]
```

but running this code throws the following error

```
undefined method `before_picture_post_process'
```

I feel like I would also have to bring in has_attached_file somewhere, but since my form object isn't active record that probably wouldn't work. Then there's also the problem of how to copy the image data over from the form object to the AllTheSteps object.

Is this even possible to do with paperclip? Is there another option that would make it feasible?

Thanks!

Comment: hi... could you find a solution to this yet? I am trying upload image attachments to a 3rd party service via my form object... i don't want to store the image in my servers.

Answer (score -2):

You can follow below steps for upload image with paperclip:

1.) Add gem into Gemfile

```
gem 'paperclip'
```

Then do `bundle install`

2.) Then generate picture attachment with this command

```
rails g paperclip report picture
```

3.) Then migrate created migration for picture

```
rake db:migrate
```

4.) Then add this in your model

```
has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :picture, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```